# Two six-sided dice are rolled. Find the probability distribution of $\max[X_1,X_2]$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am not sure if I am understanding this problem correctly. It says;

> Two six-sided dice are rolled. Let *X<sub>1</sub>* and *X<sub>2</sub>*
>   denote the outcomes of the first and second die roll respectively.
>   Define a new random variable *Y* such that:
>
> *Y* = max{*X<sub>1</sub>* , *X<sub>2</sub>*}

Does this mean I am supposed to roll the two dice and find the largest roll?

From my own understanding, if I am supposed to find the largest roll from the two dice roll, is this example of mine correct?

ex: the outcomes are {2,3} then Y=3

Moving on to what is asked of me:

> Find the probability distribution of *Y*

For this part, do I need to find all the possible outcomes of the two dice? For example;

{1,1} {1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {1,5} {1,6}

{2,1} {2,2} {2,3} {2,4} {2,5} {2,6}

{3,1} {3,2} {3,3} {3,4} {3,5} {3,6}

etc....

And do I need to find the probability of the sum of two dice? For example;

Sum = 2 , Prob = 1/36

Sum = 3 , Prob = 2/36

Sum = 4 , Prob = 3/36

etc....

After this, what do I do from here to find the probability distribution of *Y*?

If I am totally off track, explanation from you guys will be great. Sorry if it looks like I'm asking too much. Please feel free to correct me on anything!

Comment: Looks to me like you’ve mostly understand the problem correctly. For the distribution of $Y$, however, you’re not interested in the sums of the dice, but the probabilities that $Y=\max{X_1,X_2}=1$, $Y=2$, etc. So, once you’ve got your table of all $6\times6$ possible rolls, count up how many have a max. of $1$, of $2$, and so one.

Comment: The distribution has nothing to do with "sum".

Comment: Yes, thank you for referring @Max. Requested to be delete! Much help

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the mirror image of every L-shaped event corresponds to the outcome $Y$

As an example, consider the L-shaped event corresponding to the outcome $Y=3$

$$\begin{align}
                  \{1,3\} \\
                  \{2,3\} \\
\{3,1\}, \{3,2\}, \{3,3\} 
\end{align}$$

We can easily see that $$\mathbb{P}(Y=3)=\frac{5}{36}$$

In general, you can generalize that $$\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\frac{2y-1}{36}$$ where $y=1,2,3,4,5,6$

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to construct a table, with $X_1$ down the left, and $X_2$ along the top, and each cell gets the maximum of the two values.  The table below has been started for you; fill in the rest of the values.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}
  & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} \\ \hline
\textbf{1} & 1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\ \hline
\textbf{2} & 2 & 2 & 3 & & & \\ \hline
\textbf{3} & 3 & 3 & 3 & & & \\ \hline
\textbf{4} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\textbf{5} & & & & & &  \\ \hline
\textbf{6} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

The probability distribution for $Y = \max(X_1, X_2)$ can then be obtained by counting up the proportion of entries that are $1, 2, 3, \ldots$.